# Uniform Plane Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, plane-wave

Question: 
Communicating with submarines is very challenging due to the fact that seawater is a conductor (conductivity of roughly 5 S/m). This conductivity indicates that electromagnetic waves do not propagate very far into seawater. Typically, extremely low frequencies are used to communicate
due to the limited penetration depth into the seawater.
Part 1: Solve for the skin depth as a function of frequency assuming that the seawater is nonmagnetic.
Part 2: Assuming that the communication system can tolerate 30 dB of electromagnetic power loss through the seawater solve for the maximum communication depth as a function of frequency.

I'm a little confused how to answer part 2. Here's what I have, all I need is someone to either point out my mistake/ let me know I'm on the right track.

Part 1 Answer: $$\delta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{f\pi\mu_{0}\sigma}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{f\pi(4\pi \times 10^{-7} )\times 5}} = \frac{225.08}{\sqrt{f}}$$

Potential Part 2 Answer: 
$$30db = 10\log _{10}{1000}$$
$$P = \sigma E_{0}^2 = 1000 = (5)E_{0}^2$$
$$E_{0} = 10\sqrt{2}$$
Hence, 
$$E_{x} (z) = 10\sqrt{2} e^{-\alpha z} e^{-j \beta z},$$ where $\alpha = \beta = \frac{1}{\sigma}$, 
so $$E_{x} (z) = 10\sqrt{2} e^{\frac{- z \sqrt{f}}{225.08}} e^{\frac{ -jz \sqrt{f}}{225.08}}.$$

How does this answer for part 2 tell us the maximum communication depth?

Answer (score 0):

Physical quantities have *units*. The factor 1000 (30 dB) is *unitless*, so it can't be the value of $P$. (You must also specify the unit of your 225.08 in part 1.)

The factor 1000 is the attenuation. Part 2 is simply: at what depth is the wave attenuated by 1000?

Comment: Ok, when you rephrase the question like that I get a clearer understanding of what I am supposed to do

Comment: But how do I that?

Comment: Express the ratio of amplitudes at depths $z$ and $0$ and equal that to $1/1000$.